# Using getElementByID as parameter for a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I'm trying to create multiple slideShows in a single page, but when I call the function plusSlides with the parameter **document.getElementById('id').value** it doesn't work. However, if I pass a number as parameter it works.

So:

`<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>`

works just fine but I can only switch the images corresponding to the first slideShow (index = 0).

this is my code:

```
$info = [$array["images"], $array["class_slide"], $array["id_modal"]]
```

This is what I have so far for the multiple slideShows:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

  @foreach ($info[0] as $key => $image)

    <div class="{{$info[1]}}" >
      <div class="numbertext_modal"> {{$key + 1}} / {{count($info[0])}}</div>
      <img src="{{ $image }}" style="width:100%">
    </div>

  @endforeach 

  <var id='id'>{{$info[2]}}</var>
    <!-- Next/previous controls -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, document.getElementById('id').value * 1">&#10095;</a>

</div>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
 var slideIndex = [1,1,1,1,1,1];
/* Class the members of each slideshow group with different CSS classes */
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3", "mySlides4", "mySlides5", "mySlides6"] 


showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);
showSlides(1, 3);
showSlides(1, 4);
showSlides(1, 5);
/*
showAll(slideId);

function showAll(slideId){
    for (i = 0;  i < slidesId.length; i++){
      showSlides(1, i);
    } 
  }*/


function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: `<var>` elements don't have `value` properties!

Comment: I have tried using different things, but none have work so far :( what should i use?

Comment: The value is not an input, it's an already given value

Comment: I got it! thank u :)